# How do I make a case insensitive graphql query with AWS Amplify dynamoDB?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, aws-amplify

I want users to be able to make a case insensitive query to the apps AWS Amplify graphql db.

I have a less than effective filter currently implemented like so:

```
    let searchFilter = {
      or: [
        { email: { contains: enteredEmail } },
        { email: { contains: enteredEmail.toLowerCase() } }, 
        { email: { contains: enteredEmail.toUpperCase() } },
      ]
    }
    await API.graphql({ query: queries.listUsers, variables: { filter: searchFilter }, limit: 5 })
```

This grabs some of the cases, but not all, and is ugly and dumb. I would just like to do a basic case insensitive string match, figured AWS Amplify would have that functionality somewhere. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Ideally you should force rules on your application side so that the database only contains one case type. Having mixed casing in DynamoDB is not ideal as it's case sensitive.

Comment: There may be a better solution, but for "search" you can look into the @searchable schema modifier. That will pull in ElasticSearch (renamed OpenSearch because it's closed now). Check the pricing around your use case.